# `chef-client` Command Not Working in Vagrant

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am following the tutorial on [Learn Chef](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/rhel/virtualbox/configure-a-resource/) and I am stuck at step 2 on the page at this stage here:

[image]

When I run the command `chef-client --local-mode hello.rb`, it says `-bash: chef-client: command not found`. I am wondering why?

Comment: It means that it can not find chef-client in your PATH, because either chef-client is not installed or your PATH has not been updated correctly.

Comment: @JackBracken I have already installed the Chef DK on my CentOS instance though, which should already include the chef-client. What is your advice on resolving this issue?

Comment: Try `/opt/chefdk/bin/chef-client ...` (or better `/opt/chefdk/bin/chef  shell-init bash` to have a clean working environment and then you'll be able to run `chef-client`